# How to dynamically create controls based on an object (in C#/Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, configuration

I am trying to create a form based on an object. For instance, the object Configuration.cs might have a field (Color) that is made up of 3 values (RGB), as well as many other types of fields.

I have no problem with creating a class of type ColorUserControl that is added to the form dynamically, but how do I create those controls based on the fields in the object Configuration?

Here is an example of code I would **like** to be able to do...

```
Foreach (field in Configuration)
{
  if (field is Color)
  {
    add ColorUserControl to form
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement to separate the types. Then have a predefined `UserControls` for each type you store. Then fill properties via the other values in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Aparrently you can actually loop through the fields by using [.GetFields()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx)

And then can easily getType on each field